# BTRFS scrub vs balance - which one to use for regular volume maintenance?

Tags: btrfs, scrub

I understand the both scrubbing and balancing of a BRTFS volume is useful for maintaining its health. Which one is more useful though? If I cannot afford to run both types of checks regularly, should I prefer the one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

Scrubbing should be the proper action. It really checks for corrupted data.
Balancing simply re-distributes the data between the participating disks.